# Max Number Generation

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have been developing one application to register the student's details for admission. In SQL Server, I have to save the records and generate one reference number. That registration should be unique.

At the present, I am taking max number from the table and insert into the table. Duplicate records inserted in milliseconds. How to avoid duplicate records in the reference number column? In my application, 1000 concurrent users register at the same time.

Ex. IRCTC Ticket booking. They are generating PNR without duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why a regular auto increment primary key column should not suffice here:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
)
```

SQL Server would never generate a duplicate value for the above `id` column.  If, for some reason, this would not meet your expectations, then you could consider using a UUID for each student record, using the `NEWID()` function.

Comment: Here, I have concatenated that column with some text. Ex. '2019-20/B1/0001'. It will lead to duplicate reference number.

Comment: No, it won't, because if you concatenate a unique ID column with anything would most likely remain unique.  Certainly, this would be true given your date prefix.  Even if all were the same, the identity column would still be unique.

Comment: Okay. I will try this.

Comment: Above said the answer will work. But, I want to reset the number for the academic year wise. In this case, it is not suitable for me.

Comment: You don't need to do that either.  Just keep a separate date column which keeps track of the year.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do want to like '2019-20/Chn/0001'. This is my client need. In primary key, it's not possible to reset the value.

Comment: I suggest just using a PK combined with the year in this case.

Comment: Is it possible to reset primary key constraint for every academic year?

Comment: You should not need to be doing this, the combination of year and PK should ideally always be unique.

Comment: Ex. if My admission reference number will be ended with '2019-20/Chn/966', it will start with '2020-21/Chn/0001' for the next academic year.